# How to get total likes count of a post from supabase backend?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have two tables one for post and one for likes.
Post table stores all the post information.
Likes table has 3 columns

id,
post_id
user_id

Now I need help to figure out how to get total number of likes of each post through supabase query. I am using react for frontend.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('feedback')
        .select()
        .order('created_on', { ascending: false });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, you have to put in something to get something out.

Comment: this is what is I have written : const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('feedback')
        .select()
        .order('created_on', { ascending: false });

Comment: I am not asking you to code the whole APP. I am just asking about that particular query to get total likes count.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a **supabase client** for your project?

if not follow this Doc
https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js

Then import the client into the file you want to retrieve data.

you have left `.select()` empty. select can be combined with modifiers
for example, you can...

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('feedback')
  .select(`post_id`)`
```

**DOCs for reference**: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select

**You may want to have your likes and post ids on the same table** to save yourself from issues. Maybe add another column.

id, post_id user_id, post_likes

however your question is very broad hope this can point you in some of the right directions.